# replace word in character sentence in R

Tags: r, vector, character

Ok so, how do I change a word in a character vector of length 1?
To be more specific, I have the sentence "I want this book" in a character vector of length 1 apparently, and I want to replace the word "this" with "that" and then find how many words "that" exist in the sentence (which ofc will be 1).
Questions;
How do I do this?
Do I have to change something in the vector to use another code? Like make each word a unique character?
I want to do this with the simplest possible way, avoiding perplexed coding if it shall be possible...
Thank you all!

Comment: stringr package has convenient stuff like str_replace_all(), str_extract(). base package includes grepl(), strsplit(), substr(), nchar()... stuff like that.

Answer (score 4):

To count you can use:

```
stringr::str_count("I want this book", "this")
```

And to replace:

```
stringr::str_replace("I want this book", "this", "that")
```

or in base R

```
gsub("this", "that", "I want this book", fixed = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The below does what you requested.

```
myword <- "this is just that whatever mate this is it"
# 1. replace this with that
result <- gsub("this", "that", myword)
#2. count the "that" occurrences
length(unlist(strsplit(result, "that")))-1
```

or with `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_count(result, "that")
> str_count(result, "that")
[1] 3
> result
[1] "that is just that whatever mate that is it"
```